# intersection() function is not working python3

Tags: python-3.x, set, intersection

I am trying to solve this problem :
Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from `1` to `a.length`, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, `return -1`.

Example

For `a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]`, the output should be
`firstDuplicate(a) = 3`.

There are 2 duplicates: numbers 2 and 3. The second occurrence of 3 has a smaller index than the second occurrence of 2 does, so the answer is 3.

For `a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1]`, the output should be
`firstDuplicate(a) = -1`.

```
Input/Output

[execution time limit] 4 seconds (py3)

[input] array.integer a

Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ a.length ≤ 105,
1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length.

[output] integer
```

The element in a that occurs in the array more than once and has the minimal index for its second occurrence. If there are no such elements, return -1.

this is my code :

```
import math

def firstDuplicate(a):
  set1=set() 
  set2=set()
  set1=[a]
  z = len(a)
  y=z/2
  if y%2==0:
          set2 =[a[0:y]]
  else:
          set2 = [a[0:int(y)+1]]
  c = 0   
  c = intersection(a,b)
  if c == 0 :
    return -1
  else:
      if set2[1] > set2[0]:
            return set2[1]
      else:
          return set2[0]
a=[2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2]  

firstDuplicate(a)
```

it gives me error that no such function called intersection found.

Comment: While you are calling your variable `set1, set2` and initialize them to sets you immediately reassign them to lists.

Comment: Intersection is a *method* of the set type. You have to call it on a set instance. Either way,your code is seriously flawed: both set1 and set2 are overwritten with *list* instances. Each contains just wraps another list. Variable b is undefined. The result of a set intersection is a set, so it cannot equal 0. It is not possible to index a set, or intersect a list. Even if it were coded properly,that function does not implement the task.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection operator '&' results common elements in the sets.

Eg.

```
A = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
print("Intersection :", A & B)
```

Output: Intersection : {2, 4}

To find intersection from two arrays:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6]
b=[2,4,6,8,0]
i = [x for x in a if x in b]
```

array 'i' will have the values [2,4,6]